# Cannot set JQuery multiple css backgrounds, instead overwriting

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm trying to set 2 background images using JQuery. But the result is only the last image is showing.

```
$(".hero-and-content").css({ 
    "background-image": "url(files/bl_floral.png)", 
    "background-position": "bottom left",
    "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
    "background-size": "150px", 
    "background-image": "url(files/tr_floral.png)",  
    "background-position": "top right",
    "background-attachment": "fixed",
    "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
    "background-size": "150px" 
});
```

I've looked at multiple articles here. This method seems to be working for others. I'm I missing something?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: That syntax isn't working for anyone. Any object with the same key used more than once, only gets the value of the last time it's set, regardless of what that object is used for. You have to use comma separated values.

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef. Any ideas how this will look in jQuery?

Comment: Instead use: `"background-image": "url(files/bl_floral.png) no-repeat bottom left, url(files/tr_floral.png) no-repeat top right"`, than set sizes: `"background-size": "150px, 150px"` etc. Cant have any property twice, it is not CSS, but setting styles inline with elements.

Comment: `$(".hero-and-content").css( "background", "url('files/bl_floral.png') bottom left no-repeat, url('files/tr_floral.png') top right fixed no-repeat");` I just found it trying out Mohamed-Yousef's link. I can comfirm your answer @skobaljic. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Thanks to the comments on the question:

```
$(".hero-and-content").css({ 

  "background": "url('files/bl_floral.png') bottom left no-repeat, url('files/tr_floral.png') top right fixed no-repeat", 
  "background-size": "150px, 150px" 

});
```